# WPF trouble getting TextBox focused

Tags: c#, wpf

On mouse event I'm trying to create TextBox, add it to Grid, select all and focus keyboard. But can't get it working:

```
private void timeCodeEdit(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid) ((Label) sender).Parent;
    TextBox text = new TextBox();
    text.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 75, 0);
    text.Text = "aaaa";
    grid.Children.Add(text);
    text.LostFocus += lostFocus;
    Keyboard.Focus(text);
    text.SelectAll();
}
```

I've tried `Keyboard.Focus(text);` and `text.Focus();`. And if I do this:

```
private void lostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard.Focus(sender as TextBox);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I'm getting StackOverflowException, cause it lost focus right after focus.

Maybe someone can help me about this?

Comment: Try `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, txtBoxName)`

Comment: I tried but it did not help

Comment: your code works fine for me; the textbox is focused and I can type straight into it. I tried 'MouseEnter' and 'MouseLeftButtonDown' events. What .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Doing `Focus` on `LostFocus` - why do you need it?

Comment: I'm using .NET Framwork 4.5.2 and event is Label.MouseDoubleClick

Comment: @Tom1410 Sorry MouseDoubleClick works too. Please post your xaml and some more code if its there.

Comment: It seems like some other control stealing the focus.

Comment: Try adding `text.LostKeyboardFocus += Text_LostKeyboardFocus;` to your `TestBox` and handler `private void Text_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var name = ((FrameworkElement)e.NewFocus).Name;
            Console.Write(name);
        }`

Comment: This will help you to find the Control who is stealing the `Focus`

Comment: My ScrollViewer is stealing focus.

Comment: Focusable="False" for ScrollViewer helped. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Gopichandar This is the catch of adding your answer as a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post answer:

```
text.LostKeyboardFocus += Text_LostKeyboardFocus;
```

and:

```
private void Text_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var name = ((FrameworkElement)e.NewFocus).Name; 
    Console.Write(name); 
}
```

Helped me find out that my ScrollViewer is getting focus, so `Focusable="False"` for ScrollViewer solved the problem.